# Why my form is always not valid?

Tags: python, ajax, django, forms

I could submit my form using html button and it works but I want a control on a field and I use a javascript function to do that, so I changed my button and I'm calling my view with ajax.
If my form isn't valid (this mean if there are some fields empty) I want that fields bordered by red (or something like that) and possibly an error message (this field is required) like it happened before, using html button to call the view.

My `form.py`:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title_it = forms.CharField(label='Titolo (it)', widget=forms.TextInput())
    title_en = forms.CharField(label='Title (en)', widget=forms.TextInput())
    text_it = forms.CharField(label='Testo (it)', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':"20", 'cols':"100"}))
    text_en = forms.CharField(label='Text (en)', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':"20", 'cols':"100"}))
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=1)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title_it', 'title_en', 'text_it', 'text_en', 'tags', 'views')
```

My `models.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = MultilingualCharField(_('titolo'), max_length=64)
    text = MultilingualTextField(_('testo'))
    ...
```

`MultilingualCharField` and `MultilingualCharField` are about the same (probably not here the problem):

```
class MultilingualCharField(models.CharField):

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, **kwargs):
        self._blank = kwargs.get("blank", False)
        self._editable = kwargs.get("editable", True)
        #super(MultilingualCharField, self).__init__(verbose_name, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(verbose_name, **kwargs)

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, virtual_only=False):
        # generate language specific fields dynamically
        if not cls._meta.abstract:
            for lang_code, lang_name in settings.LANGUAGES:
                if lang_code == settings.LANGUAGE_CODE:
                    _blank = self._blank
                else:
                    _blank = True


                rel_to = None
                if hasattr(self, 'rel'):
                    rel_to = self.rel.to if self.rel else None
                elif hasattr(self, 'remote_field'):
                    rel_to = self.remote_field.model if self.remote_field else None

                localized_field = models.CharField(string_concat(
                    self.verbose_name, " (%s)" % lang_code),
                    name=self.name,
                    primary_key=self.primary_key,
                    max_length=self.max_length,
                    unique=self.unique,
                    blank=_blank,
                    null=False,
                    # we ignore the null argument!
                    db_index=self.db_index,
                    #rel=self.rel,#AttributeError con django 2.0
                    rel=rel_to,
                    default=self.default or "",
                    editable=self._editable,
                    serialize=self.serialize,
                    choices=self.choices,
                    help_text=self.help_text,
                    db_column=None,
                    db_tablespace=self.db_tablespace
                )
                localized_field.contribute_to_class(cls, 
                    "%s_%s" % (name, lang_code),)

        def translated_value(self):
            language = get_language()
            val = self.__dict__["%s_%s" % (name, language)]
            if not val:
                val = self.__dict__["%s_%s" % (name, settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)]
                return val

        setattr(cls, name, property(translated_value))

    def name(self):
        name_translated='name'+settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
        return name_translated


class MultilingualTextField(models.TextField):

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, **kwargs):
        self._blank = kwargs.get("blank", False)
        self._editable = kwargs.get("editable", True)
        super().__init__(verbose_name, **kwargs)

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, virtual_only=False):
        # generate language specific fields dynamically
        if not cls._meta.abstract:
            for lang_code, lang_name in settings.LANGUAGES:
                if lang_code == settings.LANGUAGE_CODE:
                    _blank = self._blank
                else:
                    _blank = True

                rel_to = None
                if hasattr(self, 'rel'):
                    rel_to = self.rel.to if self.rel else None
                elif hasattr(self, 'remote_field'):
                    rel_to = self.remote_field.model if self.remote_field else None

                localized_field = models.TextField(string_concat(
                    self.verbose_name, " (%s)" % lang_code),
                    name=self.name,
                    primary_key=self.primary_key,
                    max_length=self.max_length,
                    unique=self.unique,
                    blank=_blank,
                    null=False,
                    # we ignore the null argument!
                    db_index=self.db_index,
                    #rel=self.rel,
                    rel=rel_to,
                    default=self.default or "",
                    editable=self._editable,
                    serialize=self.serialize,
                    choices=self.choices,
                    help_text=self.help_text,
                    db_column=None,
                    db_tablespace=self.db_tablespace
                )
                localized_field.contribute_to_class(cls, 
                    "%s_%s" % (name, lang_code),)

        def translated_value(self):
            language = get_language()
            val = self.__dict__["%s_%s" % (name, language)]
            if not val:
                val = self.__dict__["%s_%s" % (name, settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)]
                return val

        setattr(cls, name, property(translated_value))
```

My `views.py`:

```
@staff_member_required
def post_new(request):
    context_dict=services.get_base_data_for_views(request)
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        print('form', form)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
        else:
            print('form.errors', form.errors)
            return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', context_dict)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    context_dict['form']=form
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', context_dict)
```

My `template.html`:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="save_post(event, 'publish')">{% trans "Pubblica" %}</button>
```

My `javascript.js`:

```
function save_post(event, action) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({type: 'POST',
    url: url_post,
    data: {
      //'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
      action: action,
    },
    success: function (lista) {
        console.log('success')
    }
  });
```

My `print(form)` in `views.py` (Campo nascosto=field hidden; Questo campo è obbligatorio=this field is required):

```
form <tr><td colspan="2"><ul class="errorlist nonfield"><li>(Campo nascosto view
s) Questo campo è obbligatorio.</li></ul></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_title_it">Titolo (it):</label></th><td><ul class="errorli
st"><li>Questo campo è obbligatorio.</li></ul><input type="text" name="title_it"
 required id="id_title_it" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_title_en">Title (en):</label></th><td><ul class="errorlis
t"><li>Questo campo è obbligatorio.</li></ul><input type="text" name="title_en"
required id="id_title_en" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_text_it">Testo (it):</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist
"><li>Questo campo è obbligatorio.</li></ul><textarea name="text_it" rows="20" r
equired id="id_text_it" cols="100">
</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_text_en">Text (en):</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"
><li>Questo campo è obbligatorio.</li></ul><textarea name="text_en" rows="20" re
quired id="id_text_en" cols="100">
</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_tags">Tag:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>Ques
to campo è obbligatorio.</li></ul><input type="text" name="tags" required autoco
mplete="off" id="id_tags" /><br /><span class="helptext">Una lista di tag separa
ti da virgola.</span><input type="hidden" name="views" id="id_views" /></td></tr
>
```

My `print(form.errors)` in `views.py` (Una lista di tag separa
ti da virgola=a tag list separated by comma):

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>text_it<ul class="errorlist"><li>Questo campo è obblig
atorio.</li></ul></li><li>text_en<ul class="errorlist"><li>Questo campo è obblig
atorio.</li></ul></li><li>views<ul class="errorlist"><li>Questo campo è obbligat
orio.</li></ul></li><li>tags<ul class="errorlist"><li>Questo campo è obbligatori
o.</li></ul></li><li>title_it<ul class="errorlist"><li>Questo campo è obbligator
io.</li></ul></li><li>title_en<ul class="errorlist"><li>Questo campo è obbligato
rio.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

If I write a new form and I leave a field empty no error is raised, but `form.is_valid` gives `False`. If I write a field and then delete it, and then submit the form that field is bordered by red and `form.is_valid` gives `False`. If I write all fields `form.is_valid` gives still `False`. So my form is never valid

edit: these lines below are not valid

If I leave `text_it` or `text_en` or `tags` empty `form.is_valid()` is `False` and I see that field with a red border (but no error message `this field is required`). If I leave `title_it` or `title_en` empty `form.is_valid()` is again `False` but I don't see any red border. Why?

Comment: In your code, when form is invalid, you pass `context_dict` which is not defined yet. Is that the code you are using?

Comment: Why should it display errors? You're submitting the form with Ajax but not doing anything with the returned response in your Ajax handler.

Comment: @Rohan: it is simplified but is that. I add the line with context_dict (a function).

Comment: @DanielRoseman The form I'm submitting have some required fields empty... it shouldn't tell me? Like I said it does for some fields and it doesn't for others. Why the difference? I must do something with the response to see the errors?

Comment: Alt! now is working! All the field empty become red. But form.is_valid=False even when they are compiled. Why my form isn't valid? Maybe the hidden input (views)?

Comment: No, it's more complicated. all the fields work in the same way: if I write a new form and I leave a field empty no error is raised, but form.is_valid gives False. If I write a field and then delete it, and then submit the form that field is bordered by red and form.is_valid gives False. If I write all fields form.is_valid gives still False... also I edit my post with some more detail